# Remove all containers command give error message

Tags: docker

I was following a tutorial on how to use docker. However, I ran into a problem when trying to remove all exited containers using

```
docker rm $(docker ps --filter status=exited -q)
```

but it gives the error message:

```
unknown flag: --filter
See 'docker rm --help'.
```

I have looked around and try the code from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) but it has the same problem. The docker version I use is 24.0.2.

[image: screenshot of my cmd]

Comment: Are you on a Un*x host (Linux or MacOS), using a Bourne-type shell (bash, zsh, ...)?  In this syntax `--filter` should be an argument to `docker ps`, not `docker rm`.

Comment: Sory I'm fairly new and I don't really understand your question. I'm on a WIndown laptop with Docker desktop installed. I believe that Docker desktop run a Unix host inside. I use cmd to pass on these commands. And yes in this command '--filter' should be an argument to 'docker ps', but somehow it is passed to 'docker rm'.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is likely due to using an outdated version of Docker that doesn't support the --filter flag for the docker ps command. The --filter flag was introduced in Docker version 1.17.0.

The best approach is to upgrade your Docker installation to a version that supports the --filter flag.

If upgrading Docker is not possible or desired, you can use this alternative method to filter containers with a specific status.

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep -i "exited" | awk '{print $1}')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My docker version is 24.0.2. I tried your command and got this message: 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.